# Recursively delete files on Windows

Tags: windows, shell

I need to remove all files and directories starts with `._` recursively:

```
find . -name \._* | xargs rm
```

How can this be done on Windows using a DOS/shell command (without Cygwin)?

Comment: Not allowed to use powershell?

Comment: can someone provide the powershell command again?

Comment: The unix command you provide above for will only work for files.  Should the contents of matching directories also be deleted?  That is, if directory ._d contains file f, should ._d be removed or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried `del /s ._*` ?

Comment: I need to do this recursively for all subdirectories/files

Comment: The /S option will delete files from all subdirectories.  If you're looking to delete subdirectories as well, you should edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: edited for deleting subdirectories and files recursively

Answer (score 1):

Download [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) . It has all the commands you listed.

Comment: looks like the link is down

Answer (score 1):

you could use a `for` loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /B /S *._*') do del "%a"
```

note this may be overkill, considering the simplicity of Adam Liss's answer.

Comment: +1 for the 'for /f' - this is the way to do xargs-ish stuff under cmd.  Could easily be modified into a complete solution: add another line for removing directories (replace 'del' with 'rmdir /s /q').  Loop until 'dir /b /s ._*' returns nothing (you have an extra * in there).

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with UNIX tools then you can try installing the [Berkeley Utilities](http://openetwork.com/berk.html) which are ports of all your favourites like grep , awk and sed etc for windows.

Comment: doesn't support pipe though...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get unix tools on windows, get those from [GNU](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html)